# Idiomatic/fast Django ORM check for existence on mysql/postgres

Tags: python, sql, django, orm, django-models

If I want to check for the existence and if possible retrieve an object, which of the following methods is faster? More idiomatic? And why? If not either of the two examples I list, how else would one go about doing this?

```
if Object.objects.get(**kwargs).exists():
    my_object = Object.objects.get(**kwargs)


my_object = Object.objects.filter(**kwargs)
if my_object:
    my_object = my_object[0]
```

If relevant, I care about mysql and postgres for this.

Answer (score 4):

Why not do this in a try/except block to avoid the multiple queries / query then an if?

```
try:
    obj = Object.objects.get(**kwargs)
except Object.DoesNotExist:
    pass
```

Just add your else logic under the except.

Comment: Is this faster than the second scenario I mentioned?

Answer (score 2):

django provides a pretty good overview of [`exists`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists)

Using your first example it will do the query two times, according to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists):

> if some_queryset has not yet been evaluated, but you
>   know that it will be at some point, then using some_queryset.exists()
>   will do more overall work (one query for the existence check plus an
>   extra one to later retrieve the results) than simply using
>   bool(some_queryset), which retrieves the results and then checks if
>   any were returned.

So if you're going to be using the object, after checking for existance, the docs suggest just using it and forcing evaluation 1 time using

```
if my_object:
  pass
```

Comment: thanks for sharing this. I was naively writing exists() function within my model classes till this point in time. I am going to use the built-in stuff henceforth